# Table generation R

Tags: r

I have a similar dataset:

```
val<-c("Y","N")
test<-data.frame(age=rnorm(n=100,mean=50,sd=10),var1=sample(val,100,T),var2=sample(val,100,T),var3=sample(val,100,T),sex=sample(c("F","M"),100,T))
```

I´d like to create a summary reporting the mean age for each category using Hmisc.

```
library(Hmisc)
summary.formula(age~sex+var1+var2+var3,data=test)
```

However, var1-var3 actually belong under the same categorical variable with levels var1,var and var3 instead of Y/N. Furthermore, these are not mutually exclusive. So, is it possible somehow to create a variable var4 with these different levels that are not mutually exclusive and type

```
summary.formula(age~sex+var4,data=test)
```

and have an output like:

```
+-------+-+---+----+
|       | |N  |age |
+-------+-+---+----+
|sex    |F| 44|48.0|
|       |M| 56|50.8|
+-------+-+---+----+
|var4   |var1| xx|yy|
|       |var2| xx|yy|
        |var3| xx|yy|
+-------+-+---+----+
|Overall| |100|49.6|
+-------+-+---+----+
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  It's not clear to me what Var4 would be or how the subsetting in the is supposed to work for Var4.

Answer (score 1):

How bout `paste0`?  (or paste(..., sep='') if you're not on R2.15)

```
> test$var4 <- paste0(test$var1, test$var2, test$var3)
> summary.formula(age~sex+var4, data=test)
age    N=100

+-------+---+---+--------+
|       |   |  N|     age|
+-------+---+---+--------+
|    sex|  F| 50|50.25440|
|       |  M| 50|51.32134|
+-------+---+---+--------+
|   var4|NNN| 13|46.64417|
|       |NNY| 17|51.34456|
|       |NYN| 15|52.92185|
|       |NYY| 17|47.35685|
|       |YNN|  9|50.91647|
|       |YNY|  7|48.04489|
|       |YYN| 10|53.23713|
|       |YYY| 12|56.14394|
+-------+---+---+--------+
|Overall|   |100|50.78787|
+-------+---+---+--------+
>
```

Comment: Not quite. Var4 should only have levels var1, var2 and var3-not all the different permutations of the levels.

Comment: so in the new var4, if var1 and var2 are `Y` you would need two entries in var4 (aka two rows in the data)?

Comment: lets say that we are dealing with cars. The dataset was entered with (var1)nissan, (var2)Lexus etc., Now each family can own moe than one car, and the aggregted car variable should contain all the cars in the family possession. Somehow, it would be very beneficial if just entering cars in the formula could result in a table with different rows for lexus and nissan without having to do this for each yes/no variable....

Comment: what value would you expect for someone with both a Nissan and Lexus?

Comment: since I'm dealing with a summary table and asking for age~cars(or var4 if you will) I'd like a summary detailing age information for each brand of cars.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in that you are trying to combine statistics for two different data sets:

1. data indexed by person:

   ```
   summary.formula(age~sex, test)

   # age    N=100
   # 
   # +-------+-+---+--------+
   # |       | |N  |age     |
   # +-------+-+---+--------+
   # |sex    |F| 35|49.99930|
   # |       |M| 65|48.96266|
   # +-------+-+---+--------+
   # |Overall| |100|49.32548|
   # +-------+-+---+--------+
   ```
2. data indexed by cars

Here you need one row per car; here is one way to create the data but I am sure there must be much nicer ways:

```
    var1 <- subset(test, var1 == "Y", c("age", "sex"))
    var2 <- subset(test, var2 == "Y", c("age", "sex"))
    var3 <- subset(test, var3 == "Y", c("age", "sex"))
    var1$var <- "var1"
    var2$var <- "var2"
    var3$var <- "var3"
    vars <- rbind(var1, var2, var3)
```

Then, the summary statistics:

```
    summary.formula(age~var, data=vars)
    # age    N=147
    # 
    # +-------+----+---+--------+
    # |       |    |N  |age     |
    # +-------+----+---+--------+
    # |var    |var1| 47|48.91983|
    # |       |var2| 43|46.31811|
    # |       |var3| 57|49.35292|
    # +-------+----+---+--------+
    # |Overall|    |147|48.32672|
    # +-------+----+---+--------+
```

As you can see, the `Overall` sections of the two summaries do not match, as they come from two different data sets. (And it is not possible to combine them the way you are asking.)